# Django: 'Response' object has no attribute 'get' when using "del request.session['key']"

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-templates, django-urls

I'm trying to practice my understanding of Django sessions and I ran into this error.
what I'm trying to do is to save a counter to count how many times a user visited the (' ') route and display it on the Django template and then the key will be destroyed when visiting the route ('/destroy').

Views.py:

```py
import re
from django.shortcuts import redirect, render
from flask import session,redirect

def index(request):
    request.session['counter']=int(request.session.get('counter',0))+1
    return render(request,'index.html')

def destroy(request):
    del request.session['counter']
    return redirect('')
```

urls.py:

```py
from django.urls import path     
from . import views
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index),
    path('destroy',views.destroy)
]
```

Template file:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Counter</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <h1>Counter</h1>
        <p>{{request.session.counter}} times</p>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Traceback:

```
Environment:


Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/destroy

Django Version: 3.2.13
Python Version: 3.6.4
Installed Applications:
['counterApp',
 'django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles']
Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']



Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Sulta\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 47, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\Sulta\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\utils\deprecation.py", line 119, in __call__
    response = self.process_response(request, response)
  File "C:\Users\Sulta\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\middleware\clickjacking.py", line 26, in process_response
    if response.get('X-Frame-Options') is not None:

Exception Type: AttributeError at /destroy
Exception Value: 'Response' object has no attribute 'get'
```

Comment: Share the full traceback...

Comment: just added it .

Answer (score 1):

You are using the `redirect` function of flask, but Django expects a Django response, so:

```
from django.shortcuts import redirect, render
from flask import session  # no redirect

def index(request):
    request.session['counter'] = int(request.session.get('counter',0))+1
    return render(request,'index.html')

def destroy(request):
    del request.session['counter']
    return redirect('index')
```

You probably should not use `session` of `flask` either. In the `urls.py`, you then give the index the proper name, such that `redirect('index')` can refer to this:

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='index'),
    path('destroy/', views.destroy)
]
```